# 1 user is not selected for my friendship query, but the rest yes, what is the issue here?

Tags: mysql, sql

My query that selects friends looks like this:

```
SELECT b.name_surname, b.avatar, b.friend_words, (b.friend_msg_id) AS friend_msg_id, COUNT(m.id) AS unread_msg FROM (
    SELECT a.name_surname as name_surname,
           a.avatar as avatar,
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.word ORDER BY w.word ASC) AS friend_words,
           (a.friend_id) AS friend_msg_id
    FROM (
      SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id,
             f1.created,
             u.name_surname,
             u.avatar
      FROM friends AS f1 
      INNER JOIN friends AS f2 ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
      INNER JOIN users AS u ON f1.asked_user_id = u.id
           AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
      WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
           AND f1.asker_user_id = :user_id
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN connections c ON c.user_id = a.friend_id 
    LEFT JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id
      WHERE c.invisible <> 1
        AND c.deleted <> 1
    GROUP BY 1
) b
LEFT JOIN messages m ON m.to_user_id = :user_id
          AND m.from_user_id = b.friend_msg_id 
          AND m.seen = 0
GROUP BY b.name_surname, b.avatar, b.friend_words, b.friend_msg_id
ORDER BY unread_msg DESC
```

sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fc65/3

It returns friends correctly for all users, except user 4. 4 is friends with 5 obviously. As 5 returns user id 4 correctly. I think this is because user 5 has no words on connections table.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best approach is breaking your query down:

The most simple query you have is:

```
SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id,
      f1.created,
      u.name_surname,
      u.avatar
FROM friends AS f1 
INNER JOIN friends AS f2 ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
INNER JOIN users AS u ON f1.asked_user_id = u.id
        AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
  AND f1.asker_user_id = 4
```

This returns :

```
FRIEND_ID   CREATED                          NAME_SURNAME   AVATAR
5           November, 05 2013 19:12:10+0000  (null)         (null)
```

Having no name_surname or avatar will make almost all your final query's values to be null, but this isn't why your query isn't returning any records:

Going out you have:

```
SELECT a.name_surname as name_surname,
           a.avatar as avatar,
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.word ORDER BY w.word ASC) AS friend_words,
           (a.friend_id) AS friend_msg_id
    FROM (
      SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id,
             f1.created,
             u.name_surname,
             u.avatar
      FROM friends AS f1 
      INNER JOIN friends AS f2 ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
      INNER JOIN users AS u ON f1.asked_user_id = u.id
           AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
      WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
           AND f1.asker_user_id = 4
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN connections c ON c.user_id = a.friend_id 
    LEFT JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id
      WHERE c.invisible <> 1
        AND c.deleted <> 1 
    GROUP BY 1
```

Here you already have no records returned. And the why is your WHERE clause. You are removing the result from the inside query, because you don't have any matches for connections for user.

To keep the result from the inner query even when you don't have any connections, either add the where clause to the ON clause:

```
LEFT JOIN connections c 
    ON c.user_id = a.friend_id AND c.invisible <> 1 AND c.deleted <> 1
```

or add :

```
WHERE c.invisible <> 1 OR c.invisible IS NULL
   AND c.deleted <> 1 OR c.deleted IS NULL
```

This will get you the following result:

```
NAME_SURNAME    AVATAR  FRIEND_WORDS    FRIEND_MSG_ID
(null)          (null)  (null)          5
```

This change makes your final query return:

```
NAME_SURNAME    AVATAR  FRIEND_WORDS    FRIEND_MSG_ID   UNREAD_MSG
(null)          (null)  (null)          5           0
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fc65/60)</kbd>

Here's your final query:

```
SELECT b.name_surname, 
       b.avatar, 
       b.friend_words, 
       b.friend_msg_id AS friend_msg_id, 
       COUNT(m.id) AS unread_msg 
FROM (
  SELECT a.name_surname as name_surname,
         a.avatar as avatar,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.word ORDER BY w.word ASC) AS friend_words,
         (a.friend_id) AS friend_msg_id
    FROM (
      SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id,
             f1.created,
             u.name_surname,
             u.avatar
      FROM friends AS f1 
      INNER JOIN friends AS f2 
          ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id 
             AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
      INNER JOIN users AS u ON f1.asked_user_id = u.id           
      WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
           AND f1.asker_user_id = 4
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN connections c ON c.user_id = a.friend_id 
              AND c.invisible <> 1 AND c.deleted <> 1
    LEFT JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id 
    GROUP BY 1
) b
LEFT JOIN messages m ON m.to_user_id = 4
          AND m.from_user_id = b.friend_msg_id 
          AND m.seen = 0
GROUP BY b.name_surname, b.avatar, b.friend_words, b.friend_msg_id
ORDER BY unread_msg DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining your thought process about debugging queries +1.

Comment: Hey, can you take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20456030/creating-friends-timeline-similar-to-facebook-mysql-query ? thanks!